# Resizing Images through controller

Tags: c#, image, image-resizing, imageresizer

Due to some reasons I have to get images through a controller , `ImageController:ViewFile(int id)`.

But then I cant use [image resizing](http://imageresizing.net/).

I have tried:

```
<img src="/File/ViewImage/4?width=100"/><br/>
```

ok for those Controller is as follows:

```
public class FileController : Controller
{
    private readonly IFileService _fileService;

    public FileController(IFileService fileService)
    {
        _fileService = fileService;
    }

    public ActionResult ViewImage(int id)
    {
        var image = _fileService.ViewImage(id);

        if (image == null)
        {
            return new HttpNotFoundResult();
        }

        return File(image.FilePath, image.ContentType, image.FileName);
    } 
    ........
```

But no luck. has anyone has same problem ?

Comment: Is it only me or is the image not showing? Could you put the things you have tried in plain formatted text?

Comment: hello. i have updated the question. You better answer now.

Comment: `return File` just returns a stream. You can resize the image with some tools and return the MemoryStream/FileStream of the resized image, or I am I not grasping your problem?

Comment: well i wanted to use this image resizing tool. It does lot of things, why would i reinvent it.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463731/diskcache-plugin-imageresizer-in-mvc3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ImageResizer Best Practices](http://imageresizing.net/docs/best-practices) explain why you should use the URL API directly instead of writing your own handler. If you need to add authentication rules or a custom data source, ImageResizer offers custom events and a plugin API for that.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by URL API, i have to return images from a controller, cause they are not in the same folder with Application, they are in a shared folder, I have a web app, and a back end within domain.